# How to make the text of a cell on Google Sheets disappears when cell itself is an active. Like exactly we made an input text hide it on active element

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I want to make ***The text on an active cell whould be like disappears and show-up the key-touch of the keyboard and got ready to type something when just that only cell itself is an active on Google Sheets***. This is whould be looks like exactly when we want to made an input text is hided on active element when that element itself is an active. Could we rich this stuff something like this whould be happend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Sheets user interface cannot be customized that way.

Comment: This is a better answer rather than the people who's doing like give me a negative response.  Thanks @doubleunary!